# MySql Ranking and Case coding issue

Tags: mysql

I have a database used for scoring, and have it filtered out by each division, and with that I needed to have SQL rank 2 separate field, the first rank is for the first event, and then a "final rank" for overall score.  I also need the ranking to rank on the total score in ascending order since the lowest score wins.

I also have a piece of code to replace the rank with a letter based on if 1 of 3 checkboxes were clicked.  So I am running into 2 issues:

1. I need some help with figuring out what code I need, or ow to integrate these two ranking codes I have, to get the outcome I am looking for, and;
2. How to use both the ranking code and the code to insert letters into the column if clicked to work together.

#1. The first bit of code I tweaked, which is what I wanted, to rank in ascending order of total, but the problem is that it ranks all of the records, not just the filtered records:

```
FIND_IN_SET(`Final Total`, (
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT `Final Total`
ORDER BY `Final Total` ASC ) FROM `Training`)) AS `Final Rank`,
```

and this is the code i found to do the ranking based on each value in a column

```
(CASE `Division Name`
WHEN @curType
THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1
ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curType := `Division Name` END
) + 1 AS `Final Rank`,
```

including this placed after the "FROM 'database name"

```
(SELECT @curRow := 0, @curType := '') r
```

So is there a better piece of code, more simplified that I can use?  because I also would like to run this on two separate columns named: "Rank" and "Final Rank"

The "Find_in_set" code will run on multiple columns, but doesn't fit my needs, however, if I put the following code in two separate columns, it breaks, for instance all records in the table will be given a number 1, instead of 1,2,3,4.

Any Ideas of how to get this to work?

#2. I have the following code to insert values into a column:

```
(CASE 
WHEN Scratched = '1' then 'S'
WHEN Withdrew = '1' then 'W'
WHEN Eliminated = '1' then 'E'
ELSE `Final Rank`
END) AS `Final Rank`
```

which works, but I also need to do ranking on this column as well, so to test it out I tried the following:

```
(CASE `Division Name`
WHEN @curType
THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1
ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curType := `Division Name` END
) + 1 AND (CASE 
WHEN Scratched = '1' then 'S'
WHEN Withdrew = '1' then 'W'
WHEN Eliminated = '1' then 'E'
ELSE `Final Rank`
END) AS `Final Rank`
```

as well as this variation

```
(CASE `Division Name`
WHEN @curType
THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1
ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curType := `Division Name` END
) + 1 OR (CASE 
WHEN Scratched = '1' then 'S'
WHEN Withdrew = '1' then 'W'
WHEN Eliminated = '1' then 'E'
ELSE `Final Rank`
END) AS `Final Rank`
```

I also tried changing the order of both codes to see if that might have any effect, which it didn't.

The problem with the above was if one on the boxes were checked, instead of placing the correct letter, it just inserted a '0' and then the rest of the rows had a rank of '1'

I know i am obviously doing something wrong, but not sure exactly what, and was hoping that someone could please give me some guidance?

here is my entire sql statement:

```
SELECT
`Number`,
`Rider Name`,
`Horse Name`,
`Division Name`,
`Level`,
`Division Type`,
`Show Type`,
`Dressage Test`,
TRIM(Score1)+0 AS Score1,
TRIM(Score2)+0 AS Score2,
TRIM(Score3)+0 AS Score3,
TRIM(Score4)+0 AS Score4,
TRIM(Score5)+0 AS Score5,
TRIM(Score6)+0 AS Score6,
TRIM(Score7)+0 AS Score7,
TRIM(Score8)+0 AS Score8,
TRIM(Score9)+0 AS Score9,
TRIM(Score10)+0 AS Score10,
TRIM(Score11)+0 AS Score11,
TRIM(Score12)+0 AS Score12,
TRIM(Score13)+0 AS Score13,
TRIM(Score14)+0 AS Score14,
TRIM(Score15)+0 AS Score15,
TRIM(Score16)+0 AS Score16,
TRIM(Score17)+0 AS Score17,
TRIM(Score18)+0 AS Score18,
TRIM(Score19)+0 AS Score19,
TRIM(Score20)+0 AS Score20,
TRIM(Score21)+0 AS Score21,
TRIM(Score22)+0 AS Score22,
TRIM(Score23)+0 AS Score23,
TRIM(Score24)+0 AS Score24,
Marks,
Penalties,
`Net Results`,
`Result Total`,
(CASE
when Scratched = '1' then '' 
when Withdrew ='1' then ''
when Eliminated = '1' then ''
else Total
END) AS Total,
Rank,
`Time Out`,
`Time In`,
timediff(`Time In`, `Time Out`) AS `Time Elapsed`,
`Speed Fault`,
`Optimum Time`,
GREATEST(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,`Time Elapsed`,`Speed Fault`), 0) AS `Under Time`,
GREATEST(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, `Optimum Time`, `Time Elapsed`), 0) AS `Over Time`,
`XC Time`,
`XC Jump`,
`SJ Time`,
`SJ Jump`,
(CASE
WHEN Scratched = '1' THEN ''
WHEN Withdrew = '1' THEN ''
WHEN Eliminated = '1' THEN ''
ELSE `Final Total`
END) AS `Final Total`,
(CASE `Division Name`
WHEN @curType
THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1
ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curType := `Division Name` END
) + 1 AS `Final Rank`,
Scratched,
Withdrew,
Eliminated,
FROM Scoring
(SELECT @curRow := 0, @curType := '') r
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What version of MySQL? (Use 8+ and then you can have ranking functions that are built in. Using 5.x forces you to use horrible techniques, which are clearly unsuited to your experience.)

Comment: The version of MySQL that my hosting provider has currently is version 5.6.32